# SQL Help regarding time greater than 7 days

Tags: sql, oracle

I was wondering if someone can help with my query. I finally got it to display all the information I need but is there any way to make it output only data for OPN 9661 that is greater than 7 days.

And OPN 9601 and 9640 to display data greater than 2 days.

Thank you in advance!

```
SELECT lma.lot, lma.device, dd.device_desc, lma.lpt,lma.opn,
CASE WHEN l.hold = 'Y' THEN 'Y'
     WHEN l.hold = 'F' THEN 'F' ELSE 'N' END AS hold,lma.arrival_dttm,
Round((SYSDATE - lma.arrival_dttm)*24,2) AS duration, lma.in_qty,
ls.lot_code3 AS location, la.operator
FROM lot_move_age  lma, lot_str ls, lot l, lot_cur_opn lco, device_def dd, lot_act la
WHERE lma.facility = 'DP1DM5' and ls.facility = 'DP1DM5'
and l.facility = 'DP1DM5' AND dd.facility = 'DP1DM5'
and lco.facility = 'DP1DM5' and la.facility = 'DP1DM5'
AND lma.grp_type = '704'
AND lma.latest = 'O'
AND ls.latest = 'Y'
AND lma.lot = ls.lot
AND lma.lot = l.lot
AND lma.lot = lco.lot
AND lma.lot = la.lot
AND lma.opn = lco.opn
AND lma.lpt = lco.lpt
AND la.tran_dttm IS NULL
AND lma.departure_dttm IS NULL
AND lma.lpt = l.lpt
AND lma.opn != '0000'
AND (lma.opn LIKE '9601' or lma.opn LIKE '9640' or lma.opn LIKE '9661')
AND lma.device = ls.device
AND lma.device = dd.device

ORDER BY arrival_dttm
```

Here is a screenshot of the table:

[image]

Comment: Please learn modern, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have duration column in your query `Round((SYSDATE - lma.arrival_dttm)*24,2) AS duration`

so... just add one more line into where section:

```
and Round((SYSDATE - lma.arrival_dttm)*24,2) >= 7
```

or if you need specific logic for OPN 9661 and 9640
that can be:

```
and (
(lma.opn = 9661 and Round((SYSDATE - lma.arrival_dttm)*24,2) >= 7)
or 
(lma.opn = 9640 and Round((SYSDATE - lma.arrival_dttm)*24,2) >= 2)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use additional condition using `case` statement in `WHERE` clause to find the conditional date difference as following:

```
And sysdate - lma.arrival_dttm >= 
    Case when lma.opn = 9661 
         Then 7
    Else 2 
    End
```

Please note that the difference between dates gives number of days between those two dates.

Cheers!!